# (Invalid RSA Private key format) I seem to be getting some sort of error within cryptography

Tags: c#, cryptography, signature

There was an issue when it was reading the Private-Key and encoding it into Base64 when was that it included non-base64 characters which is the "----BEGIN" and ----END" lines, I removed these and it seems to have fixed that error but now I am at the error in the title which is the "Invalid RSA Private key format"

(This probably isn't needed but my Private-Key begins with "MIIC" and has newlines)

I'm a newbie at cryptography and C#, I keep getting a weird error, does anyone know the solution to this problem? Thanks.

Here's piece of code that fails:

```
namespace Backend1618.Controllers
{
    public class SignatureFramework : ControllerBase
    {
        private static RSACryptoServiceProvider? _rsaCsp;
        private static SHA1? _shaCsp;

        public static void Setup()
        {
            try
            {
                string privateKeyPem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.pem");
                byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPem);
                RSAParameters rsaParams = DecodeRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes);

                _shaCsp = SHA1.Create();
                _rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                _rsaCsp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

                Console.WriteLine("[SignatureFramework] Successfully initialized SignatureFramework!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error setting up SignatureFramework: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static RSAParameters DecodeRSAPrivateKey(byte[] privateKeyBytes)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(privateKeyBytes))
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                ushort version = reader.ReadUInt16();

                if (version != 0x300)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid RSA private key format.");

                ushort modulusLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] modulusBytes = reader.ReadBytes(modulusLength);

                ushort exponentLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] exponentBytes = reader.ReadBytes(exponentLength);
                string privateKeyPem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.pem");

                while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
                {
                    int v = reader.ReadInt32();
                    privateKeyPem = v.ToString();
                }

                ushort dLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] dBytes = reader.ReadBytes(dLength);
                ushort pLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] pBytes = reader.ReadBytes(pLength);
                ushort qLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] qBytes = reader.ReadBytes(qLength);
                ushort dpLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] dpBytes = reader.ReadBytes(dpLength);
                ushort dqLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] dqBytes = reader.ReadBytes(dqLength);
                ushort inverseQLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                byte[] inverseQBytes = reader.ReadBytes(inverseQLength);
                RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters
                {
                    Modulus = modulusBytes,
                    Exponent = exponentBytes,
                    D = dBytes,
                    P = pBytes,
                    Q = qBytes,
                    DP = dpBytes,
                    DQ = dqBytes,
                    InverseQ = inverseQBytes
                };
                return rsaParams;
            }
        }
```

Changing the method of getting the Private-Key it still reports the same error.

Comment: Lucky guess: you're using 2048 bit private keys :P

Comment: Importing PEM keys is supported since .NET 5 ([ImportFromPem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-7.0)), importing DER encoded keys already since .NET Core 3.0, e.g. [`ImportPkcs8Private()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importpkcs8privatekey?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

You are using code to read a Microsoft proprietary format to read a standardized format. It's either a PKCS#1 private key (`RSA PRIVATE KEY`) or PKCS#8 private key (just `PRIVATE KEY`) in [PEM format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468).